# Javascript string does not break in new lines

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, newline

I'm trying to break string in newlines and my code looks like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      {`${t('UserName')}: ${Username}\n 
        ${t('FirstName')}: ${FirstName}\n
        ${t('LastName')}: ${LastName}`}
    </>
  );
```

When I inspect HTML it looks like it's break in new line:

[image]

But unfortunatelly this does not work.. in UI its displayed as :

[image]

Obliviously in one row..

Comment: have you try <br>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the newline characters are being treated the same as other white space because of the default `white-space` value which is `normal`

From MDN Web Docs:

> `white-space:normal` - Sequences of white space are collapsed. **Newline characters in the
> source are handled the same as other white space**. Lines are broken as
> necessary to fill line boxes.

You can use `white-space: pre-line` if you really must do your layout with `\n`.

> `white-space:pre-line` - Sequences of white space are preserved. **Lines are broken at newline
> characters**, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```js
document.getElementById("root").innerHTML="<div>123\n456</div>"
```

```css
div {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
  return (
    <>
      {`${t('UserName')}: ${Username}`<br>
        `${t('FirstName')}: ${FirstName}`<br>
        `${t('LastName')}: ${LastName}`}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Than its displayed in the UI

Comment: I have updated the answer try doing something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it a css property "whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'" few days back I was facing same issue it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your `React.Fragment` shorthand to `div`? Then, add inline style:

```
return (
    <div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}>
        {`${t('UserName')}: ${Username}\n 
        ${t('FirstName')}: ${FirstName}\n
        ${t('LastName')}: ${LastName}`}
    </div>
);
```

[image: react-newline]